# Understanding different event listener approaches

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to the Javascript world, one thing that really confuses me, and I am not entirely sure how to even *Google* it, is...

---

How does this:

```
document.querySelector('.one').addEventListener('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  this.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
}, false);
```

compare to this:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.two'), function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
  }, false);
});
```

and this...

```
var func = function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  this.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
};

document.querySelector('.three').addEventListener('click', func, false);
```

---

from what I can tell, these all do the exact same thing? Is one better from the other? Do they in fact do different things? Or is this just more inline with different methods of maintainability and scalability?

...are there other methods that are better then these?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/sqzqms3y/)

Comment: One works and the other two dont? unless you just miss-typed the sample code

Comment: `[].forEach(...` means "Do ??? 0 times", since [] represents an empty array. EDIT: Kevin's correct; sorry, I normally expect to see "Array.prototype.forEach" when non-instance usage is expected.

Comment: You just completely changed the entire premise of the question ?

Comment: I hadn't tested the code prior to posting, so I made up a fiddle, tested, and updated it with working code that shows how it all accomplishes the same task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first snippet and the last, does the same thing, one uses a named function the other an anonymous function, it makes no real difference.

This

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.two'), function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', function(event){ ....
```

gets all elements matching the selector `.two` and iterates over them and adds event listeners to all of them.

This however

```
document.querySelector('.one').addEventListener('click', function(event){
```

only gets the first element matching the selector `.one` and adds an event handler to it, any other elements matching that class is not gotten. That's the only real difference!

Comment: Thanks, and I appreciate both your answers! My apologies on my quick edits and causing you to answer twice.

Comment: No problem, it was just somewhat confusing ?

Comment: I was confused as well, I was under the assumption that `document.querySelectorAll('.one').addEventListener('click', function(event){` was actually possible when I originally asked the question. But it makes sense now why the `Array.prototype.forEach` is required in that instance as it's getting an HTMLCollection instead of just one element. (I think... hope, ha), started with jquery... transitioning to javascript... hence my confusion.